# Running FEniCS tutorial on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I am new to Ubuntu and I've been trying to run the first fenics tutorial, but I keep getting an error that says: No such file or directory.

I downloaded this first program and it is in the downloads folder of my computer, but I can't seem to be able to access it on Ubuntu.

Is there anyway that I could get this file from Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Which tutorial, from where, which first program? How did you installed Fenics/dolfin? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E "fenics|dolfin"` ?

Comment: The tutorial that I got is from the FEniCS website, https://fenicsproject.org/pub/tutorial/html/._ftut1004.html

Comment: I installed FEniCS by adding the FEniCS PPA, but I'm trying to run the first python program following the instructions for running it on a terminal window.

Comment: Whenever I type the command python3 ft01_poisson.py I get the error: No such file or directory, and I'm not sure what this means

Comment: You have to open terminal in the folder with `ft01_poisson.py` file. Or use `cd some_folder` where `some_folder` contains `ft01_poisson.py` file (replace `some_folder` with correct path). Then run `python3 ft01_poisson.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Launch terminal and type commands to add [Fenics PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Efenics-packages/+archive/ubuntu/fenics?field.series_filter=focal) and install its packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fenics
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then test your installation from terminal:

```
python -c 'import fenics'
```

---

Source: https://fenicsproject.org/pub/tutorial/sphinx1/._ftut1002.html